# Set environment variables in Jenkins Declarative Pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

Below is my code for deploy stage in jenkinsfile

```
stage('Deploy') {  
    node('slave1') {
    if ("${env.Build_testapp1}" == 'true') {
    script {
                    env.packageid = "Applications/testapp1/revesion1"
                    env.environmentId = "Environments/SysTest1/machine1"


                }
      xldDeploy serverCredentials: 'developer', environmentId: env.environmentId, packageId: env.packageid
    }
```

but how I can make it variable as per environment?

I was looking for something like this

```
if ("${env.Build_EVN}" == 'dev'){
env.environmentId = "Environments/Dev/machine1"
}
if ("${env.Build_EVN}" == 'systest1'){
env.environmentId = "Environments/SysTest1/machine1"
}
```

then using "env.environmentId" in stage('Deploy')

Comment: This looks like you really want a variable contained within the Pipeline and not an environment variable to be consumed outside the Pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

You can add one more stage before `Deploy` to handle `env.environmentId` for subsequent stages to use.

```
stage('Prepare env') {
  steps {
    script {
      if ("${env.Build_EVN}" == 'dev'){
        env.environmentId = "Environments/Dev/machine1"
      }
      if ("${env.Build_EVN}" == 'systest1'){
        env.environmentId = "Environments/SysTest1/machine1"
      }
    }
  }
}

stage('Deploy') {
  ...
}
```